# How to correspondence of unique values ​between 2 tables?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, foreign-keys

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to create a new function to work on my project.
The function will aim to detect which unique value is present in another column of another table.

At first, the function seeks to keep only the unique values ​​of the two tables, then merges them into a new dataframe

It's the rest that gets complicated because I would like to return which row and on which table my value is missing

If you have any other leads or thought patterns, I'm also interested.

Here is my code :

```
def correspondance_cle(df1, df2, col):
  df11 = pd.DataFrame(df1[col].unique())
  df11.columns= [col]
  df11['test1'] = 1

  df21 = pd.DataFrame(df2[col].unique())
  df21.columns= [col]
  df21['test2'] = 1


  df3 = pd.merge(df11, df21, on=col, how='outer')
  df3 = df3.loc[(fk['test1'].isna() == True) | (fk['test2'].isna() == True),:]
  df3.info()

  for row in df3[col]:
    if df3['test1'].isna() == True:
      print(row, "is not in df1")
    else:
      print(row, 'is not in df2')
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read the post.

Answer (score 0):

First use outer join with remove duplicates by [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for avoid removed original indices:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,5,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,20,5,8]})

col = 'a'
df = (df1[col].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
          .merge(df2[col].drop_duplicates().reset_index(), 
                 indicator=True, 
                 how='outer', 
                 on=col))
print (df)
   index_x   a  index_y      _merge
0      0.0   1      NaN   left_only
1      1.0   2      0.0        both
2      2.0   5      2.0        both
3      NaN  20      1.0  right_only
4      NaN   8      3.0  right_only
```

Then filter rows by helper column `_merge`:

```
print (df[df['_merge'].eq('left_only')])
   index_x  a  index_y     _merge
0      0.0  1      NaN  left_only

print (df[df['_merge'].eq('right_only')])
   index_x   a  index_y      _merge
3      NaN  20      1.0  right_only
4      NaN   8      3.0  right_only
```